# Maven job build on Jenkins giving error "Failed to execute default deploy goal"

Tags: maven, jenkins, artifactory

I am trying to run a Maven job on jenkins and move the artifacts to Jfrog artifactory.  The build fails with the below error.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy (default-deploy) on project MyAppMaster: Execution default-deploy of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy failed. NullPointerException -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy (default-deploy) on project MyAppMaster: Execution default-deploy of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy failed.
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:213)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:309)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:194)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:107)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.launcher.Maven35Launcher.main(Maven35Launcher.java:130)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at jenkins.maven3.agent.Maven35Main.launch(Maven35Main.java:176)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:139)
    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:70)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:212)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:54)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:369)
    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:72)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginExecutionException: Execution default-deploy of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy failed.
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    ... 31 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.deploy.DeployMojo.execute(DeployMojo.java:178)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    ... 32 more
```

I have mofified the 'server' and 'repository' tags  in pom.xml and the artifacts are also successfully pushed to artifactory. But the build fails with this error.

Can someone please guide me what might be going wrong ? There was no build failure before Jfrog artifactory integration.

Goal:

> -pl "MyApp-portlet" -am clean install  -U deploy -e

Answer (score 0):

With jfrog, you do not have to mention deploy in goals.  Making an entry into distributionManagement tag in pom.xml is enough.

I removed deploy and the job built successfully and artifacts moved as expected.

> Goal Options (Jenkins): -pl "MyApp-portlet" -am clean install  -U

Comment: If you are using the Jenkins Artifactory Plugin, it is integrating with Maven though the "install" goal, not the default "deploy" goal. That's basically all you need to do. No need to add anything to the pom.xml - all can be configured from Jenkins - https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Working+With+Pipeline+Jobs+in+Jenkins#WorkingWithPipelineJobsinJenkins-MavenBuildswithArtifactory